# Converting UIImage to PFFile results in huge file

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiimage

I want to upload an image to the parse servers. A `PFFile` can only be 10mb max, so I wrote an category to check if the `UIImage` bytesize doesn't exceeds that.

This is the code in my category:

```
- (UIImage *)scaleImageToSize:(CGFloat)destSize{
    UIImage *img = self;
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);
    NSLog(@"size: %lu", (unsigned long)[imgData length]);
    while ([imgData length] > destSize) {
        UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.9);
        NSLog(@"new size: %lu",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);
    }

    return img;
}
```

However when I call `[image scaleImageToSize:10485760];`. It's most of the time smaller than that.

However, after the having run the following line:

```
photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

the `[photoFile fileSize]` suddently exceeds `10485760`. How is that possible? How can I prevent photos from getting too large once they're a `PFFile`?

Comment: What you are doing in scaleImageToSize seems to do nothing other then convert the UIIMage to a jpeg so your log reads out the data size and possible you can get hung in your while loop. But in the end you are just return the same UIIMage. And then when you are trying to save to a PFFile you are using a PNG so what was the point of the jpeg calc in the first place.  Or am i missing something?

Comment: You're trying to make the image exactly 10MB and then you're trying to create a PFFile object with an image that is already 10MB, the PFFile object has some overhead. Together they will be larger than the 10MB limit. Your image needs to be smaller than 10MB so that the PFFile can be smaller than 10MB. Maybe make it 9.5MB?

Comment: The idea is to compress the img to a lower resolution until it is low enough to be passed into a PFFile. However, I haven't been able to test it yet since it does not get stuck in the while loop but just get right past it; meaning it has a smaller size than the 10mb.

Comment: @Garfbargle My latest log was called when I logged `size` and it returned `size: 5247124`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your scaleImageToSize does nothing meaningful -- other than provide you with some info on the jpeg size. If you want to store the image and it is less the 10MB as jpeg then store it as jpeg not png.

so try this instead

```
photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];
```

My guess is this is what you really want

```
photoFile = [PFFile fileWithData:[self scaleImageToSize(10485760)]];

- (NSData *)scaleImageToSize:(CGFloat)destSize
{
    UIImage *img = self;
    CGFloat compress = 1.0;
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compress);
    NSLog(@"size: %lu", (unsigned long)[imgData length]);
    while ([imgData length] > destSize) {
        compress -= .05;
        imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, compress);
        NSLog(@"new size: %lu",(unsigned long)[imgData length]);
    }

    return imgData;
}
```

This could be slow so you may want to do this in a block off the main thread.